# addjs to custom admin module not working

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, theme

I am trying to add a js file in my admin custom module. Here is my `config.xml` -

```
<config>
       ....                
<adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <inventory_uploads>
                    <file>uploads.xml</file>
                </inventory_uploads>
            </updates>
        </layout>
</adminhtml>
       ....
</config>
```

`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/uploads.xml` -

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_uploads_index>
            <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>uploads/jscolor/jscolor.js</script></action>
            </reference>
    </adminhtml_uploads_index>
</layout>
```

doesn't understand, what went wrong in this code.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you forget include `<?xml version="1.0"?>` in your layout?

Try to determine if you layout working well. If your header will disappear - it will mean that layout loaded properly.

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_uploads_index>
        <remove name="header" />
    </adminhtml_uploads_index>
</layout>
```

If it doesn't work - try this:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="header" />
    </default>
</layout>
```